# can't find tomcat directory after installing with easy apache on VPS

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat, vps, installation

I have installed tomcat with my build using easy apache on my VPS. This seemed to set up fine with no error messages. But I cannot find any tomcat directory on my VPS (I thought that one should have been created in the installation process?). I have tried using SSH and typing

```
whereis tomcat
whereis tomcat6
whereis tomcat7
```

These just return

```
tomcat:
```

etc.

I would appreciate any tips on what I might be doing wrong. I'm a VPS / server newbie.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
find / -name server.xml
find / -name webapps
```

But the easiest way is to use the zip version. Download, unzip and ready.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. So find / -name webapps gave me lots of useful paths to tomcat such as '/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps' and 'home/cpeasyapache/src/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps'. However once I start trying to navigate to these directories ('cd usr' or 'cd home') I get '-bash: cd: usr: No such file or directory' Do you know why this is happening? Many thanks, Paul